# table view when i deleting 1st row one more row is adding at the last cell which is last cell information

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have created a table view. Each  of my row has a delete button. Now, when I am deleting first row, the last row is being added one more time to the table view.

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(currentHTMLElement==@"1") {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier=@"Cell";
        UITableViewCell* cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if(cell == nil) {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault    reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *d = (NSMutableDictionary *) [arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        retun cell;
    }
}
```

I have some more labels in each row. Also, I reload the table view.

Comment: what is written in your nuber of rows method?

Comment: Reduce your datasource also..

Comment: return array count where i have added list to the array.

Comment: Did you reload table view after delete using [tableview reloadData] ?

Comment: i reloaded the tableview

Answer (score 0):

May be replace `currentHTMLElement==@"1"` with `[currentHTMLElement isEqualToString:@"1"]`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you delete it in this way:

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
//delete item form you array (arr)
//delete row from tableView
[self.tableView reloadData];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Comment: actually i am laoding my table view from database and we are deleting the first row using button . when button actions we are deleting in database by calling service before   relaoding data .